# What does it mean when a return keyword can't be followed by an object expression?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void OnMouseUp()
    {
        // 2
        if (CanPlaceInfantry())
        {
            // 3
            infantry = (GameObject)
                Instantiate(infantryPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            // 4
            AudioSource audioSource = gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
            audioSource.PlayOneShot(audioSource.clip);

            gameManager.Gold -= infantry.GetComponent<InfantryData>().CurrentLevel.cost;

        } else if (CanUpgradeInfantry())
        {
            infantry.GetComponent<InfantryData>().IncreaseLevel();
            AudioSource audioSource = gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
            audioSource.PlayOneShot(audioSource.clip);

            int cost = infantryPrefab.GetComponent<InfantryData>().levels[0].cost;
            return infantry == null && gameManager.Gold >= cost;
        }
    }
```

when I run my code I get error CS0127: Since 'PlaceInfantry.OnMouseUp()' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression. I don't know what to do about this error. Don't know whats going wrong.

Comment: The code you have posted will not cause that error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to return something from the PlaceInfantry.OnMouseUp() method (which you haven't shown in your question).  A void method can return nothing but it can't return something.

A method that returns void can include:

```
return;
```

But it can't include:

```
return someObjectOrValue;
```

Answer (score 2):

You've posted the wrong code. The root of your error is that `PlaceInfantry.OnMouseUp()` has been declared as a void function but it returns something, like this:

```
void OnMouseUp()
{
    // ... code here
    return (something);
}
```

Remove the return statement or change the void declaration.